# md-autocomplete in angular material - how to keep the class "md-not-found"

Tags: angular-material, md-autocomplete

The md-autocomplete provides a class named md-not-found in the md-virtual-repeat-container when you are trying to search for an element that does not exist in the dropdown, displaying an error message underneath. When you remove focus from the input element, the md-not-found is removed. The autocomplete therefore gives a false impression of having a valid input, as the user is not presented with any feedback.

Is there any way to keep the class "md-not-found", even after you unfocus the input element?

md-autocomplete official demo: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

**Update**

I have made a temporary solution:

```
<label class="{{selectedItem !== null || searchText === '' ? '' : 'label-error'}}">Name</label>
```

The label-error class applies a red color.

The solution is not an answer to the question per se, but offers an alternative quick fix

Answer (score 0):

I used md-autocomplete inside the md-chips and its working as well as you want. 
When request return noContent(204) md-not-found is being visible and it isn't disappear until user start texting again.

```html
<md-content layout="column">
   <md-chips
              class="md-input"
              ng-model="myItem"
              md-autocomplete-snap
              md-on-add="change()"
              md-on-remove="change()"
              required
              md-require-match="true"
              md-transform-chip="reformr($chip)"
              md-separator-keys="keys">
<md-autocomplete md-selected-item="selectedItem"
                               md-no-cache="true"
                               md-search-text="search.text"
                               md-items="item in getSuggestedItems()"
                               md-item-text="item.name"
                               md-min-length="0"  
                               placeholder="{{ 'textItemName' | translate }}"
                               required
                               md-input-name="suggestedItem"
                               md-search-text-change="listSuggestedItems(search.text)">
                <span md-highlight-text="search.text" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.name}}</span>
                <md-not-found>
                  {{'no_item_found' | translate}}
                </md-not-found>
              </md-autocomplete>
  </md-content>
```

Comment: need help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528680/md-autocomplete-not-found-passing-the-old-values-when-we-submit-the-form